# Rocket Universe rounding a decimal

Tags: rounding

Trying to check if a number field has anything other than 0 following the dot.

So 50.10 would have 10

50.00 would have 0 etc

Vaguely remember a rounding function but that might have been in R83 or another flavour

Comment: Can't you use modulo? `5.1 % 1` - I've never used Rocket or Universe, but most modern systems that support arithmetic support modulo, AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I would handle it as a string. The problem with doing it mathematically is that it loses the trailing 0s, which you appear to want based on your criteria and expected output.

If you know the precision (which you might because generally these things are stored as integers with a conversion applied to it display the decimal point) you can just take the last X Characters of the value using the [X] notation, or if you don't you could use FIELD to get everything after the ".", which is probably safer. If you need that to be an actual number at the other end just multiply the value by one, which will keep you 10 and make your 00 a 0.

```
TEST.VAL.1 = "50.10"
TEST.VAL.2 = "50.00"
TEST.VAL.3 = "50.1230"

CRT MOD(TEST.VAL.1,1) ;* returns 0.1
CRT MOD(TEST.VAL.2,1) ;* returns 0
CRT MOD(TEST.VAL.3,1) ;* returns 0.123

CRT TEST.VAL.1[2] ;* returns 10
CRT TEST.VAL.2[2] ;* returns 00
CRT TEST.VAL.3[2] ;* returns 30

CRT FIELD(TEST.VAL.1,".",2) ;* returns 10
CRT FIELD(TEST.VAL.2,".",2) ;* returns 00
CRT FIELD(TEST.VAL.3,".",2) ;* returns 1230
END
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it.  One way is this:

```
NUMBER = 50.10
RESULT = FIELD(NUMBER,'.',2) ;* returns 10
```